# $\frac1z$ integrable on every compact set K

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I want to show that $\frac1z$ is integrable on every compact set K in $\mathbb{C}$

I know that $\frac 1z$ ist integrable on $\overline{D}=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:\lvert z\rvert \le 1\}$ by
$$\int\int_{\overline{D}} \frac 1{\lvert z\rvert} d(x,y)=\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}\frac 1{\lvert re^{it}\rvert}\lvert ire^{it}\rvert dtdr=\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}\frac 1r rdtdr=2\pi <\infty$$

Now I am not sure how to go on. I thought of mapping the compact set to $\overline{D}$. But the mapping must be homeomorphic (I think) and I am not sure if this is possible.
Is this even the right approach?

Comment: If by integrable you mean that the modulus is integrable with respect to the Lebesgue measure of the plane, then I would say that whether or not $0$ is anywhere is irrelevant.

Comment: If $0 \notin K$ there is no problem as $1/z$ is continuous; if $0 \in K$ it must be in the interior of $K$ by hypothesis, so there is a small closed disc $D_0(r) \subset K$; since $1/z$ is continuous on $K- D_0(r)$ it is integrable there, while on $D_0(r)$ use the computation in the post to show integrability, hence $1/z$ integrable on $K$; @Gae note that if $K$ is a circle (or a segment) containing $0$ the result fails if interpreted in the natural context of path integrals - I agree that there is ambiguity in defining integrability here though